# Почему не срабатывает считывание текста с jTextField?

Tags: java, swing

Почему не срабатывает считывание текста с jTextField? из-за этого не могу запустить диалоговое окно при условиях.

вот код с методом, где не срабатывает считывание текста с jTextField

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
       if(jTextField1.getText() == "" || jTextField2.getText() == "" || jTextField3.getText() == ""){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Введите переменные!!!");    
       }else{
            x = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
            y = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
            z = Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
            a = (x * z + (y * z) / (Math.pow(x, 2) + 4 * x + Math.exp(1))) * ((2 * x + y) / (Math.exp(2 * Math.pow(z, 2)) + Math.tan(Math.cos(Math.sin(x + y + z)))));
            b = (1 + Math.cos(Math.pow(Math.PI, y - x))) / (Math.pow(Math.sin(z), 2) + Math.pow(Math.cos(y), x));
            s = "a(x, y, z) = " + a;
            s_2 = "b(x, y, z) = " + b;
            jLabel7.setText(s);
            jLabel8.setText(s_2);
            }
        
    }
```

Вот весь код GUI с логикой:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.test;

import javax.swing.*;
/**
 *
 * @author Matrix
 */
public class swingForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
    double x,y,z,a,b;
    String s, s_2;

    /**
     * Creates new form swingForm
     */
    public swingForm() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 255));
        setResizable(false);

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Введите х:");

        jLabel2.setText("Введите y:");

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel3.setText("Введите z:");

        jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel4.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Matrix\\IdeaProjects\\App_13\\task_13.png")); // NOI18N

        jButton1.setText("Очистить");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("Вычислить");
        jButton3.setToolTipText("");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 117, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel4)))
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 90, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                                .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 90, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addComponent(jLabel7, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel8, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGap(55, 55, 55))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        
       if(jTextField1.getText() == "" || jTextField2.getText() == "" || jTextField3.getText() == ""){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Введите переменные!!!");    
       }else{
            x = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
            y = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
            z = Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
            a = (x * z + (y * z) / (Math.pow(x, 2) + 4 * x + Math.exp(1))) * ((2 * x + y) / (Math.exp(2 * Math.pow(z, 2)) + Math.tan(Math.cos(Math.sin(x + y + z)))));
            b = (1 + Math.cos(Math.pow(Math.PI, y - x))) / (Math.pow(Math.sin(z), 2) + Math.pow(Math.cos(y), x));
            s = "a(x, y, z) = " + a;
            s_2 = "b(x, y, z) = " + b;
            jLabel7.setText(s);
            jLabel8.setText(s_2);
            }
        
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swingForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swingForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swingForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(swingForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new swingForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel8;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: import для лохов?

Comment: А где считывание текста с JLabel?

Comment: спутал немного) там jTextField

Comment: насчёт import, да вижу что можно было просто использовать его, но мне не позволил это сделать NetBeans, я почему то не могу изменять название методов и компонентов

Comment: это условие не работает if(jTextField1.getText() == "" || jTextField2.getText() == "" || jTextField3.getText() == ""), что то не так с getText()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы сравнить 2 строки в java, надо использовать метод [String.equals()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

```java
jTextField1.getText().equals("") || jTextField2.getText().equals("") || jTextField3.getText().equals("")
```

Но в данном случае лучше использовать [String.isEmpty()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()):

```java
jTextField1.getText().isEmpty() || jTextField2.getText().isEmpty() || jTextField3.getText().isEmpty()
```

Comment: я совсем забыл об equals, спасибо большое)) я просто недавно стал учить джаву, после питона, ещё не привык